# MySQL one column equal another?

Tags: php, mysql

How in php/mySQL can i make a column equal another column?

id is auto increment, xid should be unique. Can i make xid = id in SQL? (the reason for this is to log changes but i'll explain more if needed)

To make xid unique the best way is to copy the auto increment of id

```
+----+-----+----------+----------------+------+---------+
| id | xid | title    | body           | page | visible |
+----+-----+----------+----------------+------+---------+
|  1 |  1  | my title | my body        | NULL |       1 | 
|  2 |  2  | my title | my body edited |    1 |       0 | 
+----+-----+----------+----------------+------+---------+

$queryX = "INSERT INTO table (xid, title, body, page, visible) 
VALUES (, 'Plays', 'it's playing', 'book page', 1)";
```

Comment: I think you need to explain a little more as to what you are trying to achieve doing this?

Comment: Andy is right. There is no reason I can think of that you would need to have two columns in a table that always equal one another.

Comment: does this go against the rules of 1NF?

Comment: The reason to do it is due to a lack of understanding about Drupal databases. Although i shouldn't (it is the only way i can think of doing what i want), i need to write to the database directly and nid and vid are both unique. But answer works great, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to do this, but my approach would be using two queries and [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

```
INSERT INTO table (title, body, page, visible) 
VALUES ('Plays', 'it''s playing', 'book page', 1);
UPDATE table SET xid = id WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

You may want to do this using a [`TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html), so you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: There's a foot seeking bullet if I've ever seen one. =)

Answer (score 0):

In one query:

```
INSERT INTO table (xid, title, body, page, visible) VALUES 
( SELECT MAX(xid) + 1, .... )
```

it will put unique xid, can be done with id also, I not quite sure I undestand the need...